# psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation - when tring to to import exported csv file from another db

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, postgresql, dataframe, psycopg2

I have an two postgre DBs (on aws), one with table called `test`, and second that is empty.

I want to export the `test` table using pandas dataframe (so I could change its values), then import it to the second DB.

**I tried to do three steps:**

1. Exported and imported (using pg_dump) the structure of the db and table, to the second DB (`pg_dump --schema-only`).
2. Copy the table to dataframe.
3. Exported the `test` table to csv, then import it to the second db.

On the third stage, I got the following error:

```
psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type integer: "id"
CONTEXT:  COPY test, line 1, column id: "id"
```

**I did successfuly step 1.**

This is the columns of `test` table:

```
id (int)| num (int)| name (text)| data (text)
```

**Step 2:** This is how I loaded the first table to DataFrame:

```
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM %s" % self.table, self.conn)
```

**Step 3:**
This is how I exported the `test` table:

```
   def export_to_csv(self, csv_path):
        self.df.to_csv(csv_path, sep=',', index=False)
```

This is my csv file I got from the export:

```
id,num,name,data
1,100,April Villegas ,23427620
2,200,Matthew Bautista ,67576160
3,300,Debbie Cruz ,4505507
4,400,Michelle Long ,67834306
5,500,Valerie Mendez ,22273437
6,600,Clayton Davis ,6196349
```

And this is how I tried to import it back (to the second DB - after importing the schema from step 1):

```
def import_table_from_file(self, table_file_path):
    if table_file_path.endswith('.csv'):
        f = open(table_file_path, 'r')
        self.cur.copy_from(f, self.table, sep=',')
        f.close()
```

Again - this is the error I got:

```
psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type integer: "id"
CONTEXT:  COPY test, line 1, column id: "id"
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Why not just  `pg_dump -t <the_table> -f table.sql` from the first database. Then `psql -f table.sql` to the second database and then change the values in the second database.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I cant. Its a sensitive data, I cant put it in the second db before altering the data.

Comment: The error is due to the string "id" being submitted as a value for the integer column `id`. Somewhere in your transformation you are substituting the column name for the column value. Step through the process to see where? I just realized where that might be. I'm betting `df.to_csv` is creating a header line and that is being passed in to `copy_from`.

Comment: Yeah, from here [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) the default is `header=True`. Try `self.df.to_csv(csv_path, sep=',', header=False, index=False)`